# Isolated Storage - Read text file from last row to first

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I am trying to read a txt file, from last row to first. It's like this, actually:

```
randomWord1
randomWord2
randomWord3
...
```

I'd need to start reading from randomWord3, back to randomWord1, placing every line in a LongListSelector I have already tested out.

I can actually read it from 1 to 3 via this code:

```
while (!reader.EndOfStream){
    rigaStorico.Add(new Storico(reader.ReadLine()));
}
```

How can I actually do the exact same, but from 3 to 1? I can't figure that out!

p.s. Of course, the number of rows is NOT KNOWN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two simple options using built-in functionality:

Use `Reverse` ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0axc2h2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

```
var rigaStorico = new List<Storico>();

while (!reader.EndOfStream){
    rigaStorico.Add(new Storico(reader.ReadLine()));
}

rigaStorico.Reverse();
```

Or, you could always `Insert` ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) at the beginning of the list the new item:

```
var rigaStorico = new List<Storico>();

while (!reader.EndOfStream){
    rigaStorico.Insert(0, new Storico(reader.ReadLine()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a simple solution - as you don't know numer of rows, read them all then add to LLS:

```
List<Storico> temp = new List<Storico>();
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    temp.Add(new Storico(reader.ReadLine()));
}
for(int n = temp.Count - 1; n >= 0; n--)
    rigaStorico.Add(temp[n]);
```

**EDIT**
Althouh this solution works, it needs a temporary List - in fact there are better solutions provided by @WiredPrairie

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ought to work well for you.

```
public void ReadBackwards(string fileName)
{         
    StreamReader fileStream = new StreamReader(fileName);

    fileStream.BaseStream.Seek(1024, SeekOrigin.End);
    char[] arr = new char[1024];
    while (fileStream.BaseStream.Position > 0)
    {
       arr.Initialize();
       fileStream.BaseStream.Seek(1024, SeekOrigin.Current);
       int bytesRead = fileStream.Read(arr, 0, 1024);
    }
}
```

//KH.

Comment: How does this answer the question? The code you show doesn't do anything with a `List` nor does it deal with `EOL` characters.